# android.support.v7.widget.toolbar is not found in java file using android studio?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-toolbar

I have created a toolbar xml file and want to add in MainActivity.

i have include toolbar.xml file in MainActivity layout file

Toolbar.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/dark_blue">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Main Activity Xml Layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="hogwart.harrypotter.bucketdrop.ActivityMain">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
    <include layout="@layout/empty_drops"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then i want to add toolbar to main activity via java code but here it shows one toolbar :

```
import android.widget.Toolbar;
```

But support toolbar is not found :

```
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
```

Main Activity Code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Toolbar;

public class ActivityMain extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Gradle file code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "hogwart.harrypotter.bucketdrop"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
}
```

Comment: post your `build.gradle`

Comment: i have added above gradle file coe

Comment: i did it but still same

Answer (score 13):

Wherever you want to use it in XML or in java instead of `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` use `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar` and it should work just fine

Answer (score 6):

Add below code in your dependency.

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
}
```

And this toolbar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:id="@+id/toolbar"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
 android:background="#1b5e20"
 local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
 local:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 4):

Add the following dependency in your gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
```

This library has the support toolbar you are looking for. If this still does not solve the problem, try invalidating cache and restart android studio.

Comment: I get `WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.` should `compile` in this answer simply be switched with `implementation`?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe, you are using AndroidX. Please check it. Also, you should update your libraries for AndroidX. For this you should use 29 version.

```
compileSdkVersion 29
```

And if you want to use Toolbar add this on your gradle file (Module:app):

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

Use this Toolbar code in your XML file:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar />
```

Answer (score 2):

replace `import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;` with `import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add ***Proper*** *App Compact* **V7 support support library** dependency to your application via **build.gradle** file.

You should call

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
```

Then

1. **Clean project**
2. **Rebuild project**
3. **Sync Gradle**

Comment: still this import android.widget.Toolbar; is showing

Comment: @ManishTiwari manually remove `import android.widget.Toolbar;` and put `import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
`

Comment: `Update your android repository`

Comment: @ManishTiwari Facing same problem yet ?

Comment: @ManishTiwari JI Comment out `testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'` for test case .

Comment: what i did, first comment `testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'` and then add `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'` to gradle and sync. After this clean project and rebuild project. But nothing happend, same issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107400/discussion-between-manish-tiwari-and-intellij-amiya).

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Reminder: Please check maybe your theme is selected to "NoActionBar" try changing it to **AppTheme**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to convert support views like ConstraintLayout ViewPager from support v4/v7 to androidx and you don't know the package name of every view, just press Crtl + space

Example

```
     <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp">

             ...

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

All you need to do is to delete the package name of the view (in this case android.support.constraint) and just put the cursor after the name ConstraintLayout and press Crtl + space and it will auto complete the package for you.

To this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">


   ...
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This solution might be trivial for some people but I figured it would be helpful for others that don't know this.

Answer (score 0):

I have a same problem and i fix it by correct paths:

my toolbar.xml was placed in values/toolbar.xml, and correctm path is the:
layout/toolbar.xml